# Is there a word which describes a thing which has been dispatched?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

For instance, let's say I dispatch a truck to deliver a thing, but I could also dispatch an individual to pick something up.  How could I refer to either of those things without having to say "dispatched *truck*" or "dispatched *person*"?

I know I can just say "dispatched thing" or "dispatched item", but are there any terms that can encompass all things which could be dispatched?

I don't know if this would be a separate question, but could I perhaps refer to all things related *to* some dispatch event as a dispatch map or something?

Comment: Unfortunately OED doesn't contain any mentions of *dispatchee* (as a corollary to *dispatcher*) at all.

Comment: courier?         .......

Comment: While dictionary definitions only support using this noun for the content of a message, I believe that most people would understand calling that *dispatched thing* a **[dispatch](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dispatch)** (noun definition).

Comment: Could you supply an example sentence with a gap for the word you want, please?

Comment: I don't think my question is very good.  I'm not sure of a better way to ask it, because I'm not entirely sure where I was trying to go with it. @Davo, I've taken your comment as the answer.  If you make it the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While dictionary definitions only support using this noun for the content of a message, it's not much of a stretch, and I believe that most people would understand calling *that dispatched thing* a ***dispatch***. From OLD:

> **[dispatch](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dispatch)**
>
> 2  An official report on state or military affairs.
>    *‘in his battle dispatch he described the gunner's bravery’*
>
> 2.1 A report sent in from abroad by a journalist.
>    *‘he conducted meetings for the correspondents and censored their dispatches’*

Example:

> That dispatch left here at 0920 hrs, and it arrived at the destination at 1035 hrs.